# Supress jitter in measured values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

in my application a receive measurement data from a external library. It's about a dataset of 20 3D Points 30 times per second. I've realized some jitter in the data and I'm looking for a way to supress or better flatten peaks out of the data stream without significantly slowing down the whole system. Unfortunately I have to rely on the last dataset I receive so I can't record the data (lets say in a Queue) and filter out "bad" values. But I could record data and try fitting an incoming value to the recorded data.

Is there any approved and reliable algorithm for this problem?

Thanks in advance

FUX